# What does emacs do to apply a major-mode?

Tags: events, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I've read most of the manual and am slowly getting my head around the things I need to make major-modes, etc.  I've not ran into anything that explains the loop/cycle that Emacs goes through to apply the major mode (or minor-mode even).

For example: I type `if` while in go-mode and suddenly `if` is syntax-highlight.  I know that just typing common letters amounts to `self-insert-command`.  So how does emacs then react to the change in the buffer unless either self-insert-command fires and event or just changing the buffer fires and event?

Comment: Please narrow your question to something specific.  You start by saying you want to understand the cycle of events that occur when enabling a major-mode, and then you meander into something about `if` and syntax, and then go on with changing buffers . . .  The question as it stands now should be closed as being too broad.  Some of what happens is written in C and baked into the Emacs executable, and some of it is Lisp.  I've been using Emacs extensively for 3.5 years, and I can say that nothing is simple -- you can spend hours/days tracing backwards to find the source of where something began.

Comment: To begin upon the long and never-ending journey that is Emacs, you can start by using the following functions:  `M-x describe-key` and then type a keyboard shortcut and that will give you the name of the function.  You can follow the link with your mouse if you have the source-code installed.  If you know the name of the function or variable or face and you want to read the source-code, type `M-x find-function` or `M-x find-variable` or `M-x find-face`.  If you have the c-source code installed and the variable to its location set properly, you can also use Emacs to jump to the source code.

Comment: Emacs has a huge amount of general capabilities, and any given mode can hook into those abilities (and implement new ones on top). Modes (or indeed any other code) can arrange for things to happen at certain times, frequently by adding a function to a *hook* (`post-command-hook` and `self-insert-hook` are two rather general-purpose examples), or by the use of *timers* (both normal and *idle* varieties). Any *specific* feature might work differently to any other, though. As far as a loop/cycle goes, at the top level is `C-h i g (elisp) Command Loop` and everything else happens from there.

Comment: `font-lock` is the system for syntax highlighting.  Read the manual and/or code that defines any major mode to see how it works.  Which major modes is used for a given file is generally decided with `auto-mode-alist`.  Minor modes are usually either global (always on) or turned on in a major mode's hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W.r.t syntax highlighting, this is triggered by any change to the buffer, no matter which command is used.  To do this, the package taking care of keeping the highlighting up-to-date (typically jit-lock on behalf of font-lock) uses `after-change-functions`.  See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `after-change-functions` <kbd>RET</kbd> and also check the corresponding documentation in the Emacs Lisp reference manual (reachable from the "Help" menu).